# FFMPEG VBS process simultaneous files

Tags: ffmpeg, vbscript

I need to achieve to process multiple video files simultaneously rather then in series. The below code processes files to be one after another. How can I run multiple ffmpeg sessions to convert the files simultaneously

The below code is working fine but processes one file at a time:

```
For Each oFile In folderFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestFiles").Files
   If UCase(folderFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "MXF" Then
     strSplashImagePath = Left(oFile.Name, Len(oFile.Name) - 4) & ".mp4"
     Cmd = "cmd.exe /c ffmpeg.exe -y -i ""C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestFiles\"&oFile.Name&"""  -ab 128k -acodec aac -ac 2 -strict -2 -b:v 12000k -f mp4 -g 34 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec h264 -preset ultrafast ""C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestFiles\"&strSplashImagePath&""""
     objShell.Run Cmd, 10, True

   end if
```

Next

Comment: When in doubt check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84)).

Comment: thanks for pointing out bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is found working as follows:

```
objShell.Run Cmd, 10, False
```

With this set to false, it doesn't blocks the vbs thread.